# How to deploy an XSD grammar in a glassfish server

Tags: glassfish-3

I have a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5) server running. I have an application which generates on the fly xml files. This files must be validated against an XSD grammar which is provided as a file. Other applications need to validate xml files against this grammar. I would like to deploy this grammar as a static local file so that this grammar is reachable via a local URL.

This is not a problem if I put it manually under the `docroot` directory. I would like to deploy it inside a `war` file so that no manual action is required.

The question is how to do this and under which URL will be available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your application produces xml files based on xsd, I think you should use JAXB for generation. This will make you sure all xml files are validated.

Second, you can place your xml file in a web app, and you can publicate it, like WebContext/xml file, and configure your web.xml to make all *.xsd files as available, and downloadable.